# Regression coefficients for (un)known $\sigma_x^2$

Tags: regression, variance, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I'am currently reading an article *A Paradoxical Result in Estimating Regression Coefficients* (can be found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4302277/#S2title) and at the end of the second paragraph (**2 Estimating the Slope When the Variance is Known**) there is written:

> What is driving the superiority of the least-squares estimate over the
> estimate that uses more information, is that the least-squares
> estimate is exploiting the dependence between $s_{xy}$ and to obtain a more
> efficient estimate of $β_1$ than the one obtained by using only $s_{xy}$ and
> knowing $\sigma_x$.

And as I think of it I cannot really find a good explanation why this is the case, precisely why in this case least-square estimate is superior?

Comment: Perhaps because there will be errors in estimating the covariance, and these are partially offset when estimating the standard deviation and taking the ratio

Comment: @Henry thanks for the reply! Could you please explain more precisely what you mean by that?

Comment: Suppose as  an example your $|x_i - \bar x|$ happen to be smaller than might be expected.  Then $\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{(n-1)\sigma_X^2}$ might be closer to $0$ than expected but $\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}$ might be less affected overall if the numerator and denominator have both moved in the same direction. There could be a similar effect if your $|x_i - \bar x|$ happen to be larger than might be expected.  So when $s^2_x$ and $\sigma_X^2$ differ, you may have $s_{x,y}$ and $\sigma^{\,}_{X,Y}$ differing in a similar way so better not to mix them